# When were the most recent Amendments to the boundaries of Boston Ward 3?

Tags: united-states, cities, political-geography

When were the most recent Amendments to the boundaries of Boston Ward 3? What were the changes at the time?

[image]

Comment: Have you done any preliminary research? Does [this](http://hue.uadata.org/assets/documentation/Boston_Ward_History.pdf) answer from google help?

Comment: >"Have you done any preliminary research?" yep. >"Does this answer from google help?" yep, any more recent?

Comment: I don't know what category this question falls under, but its not history.

Comment: I'm betting OP has a reason for asking this other than idle curiosity about Boston's Ward 3, although I prefer Boston's [Ward 8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ward_8_(cocktail)). I see no need to close just because the question is boring.

Comment: Summary.
What is the Authority for the current Boundaries of Boston Ward 3 ?... maps aren't accompanied by a list of sources. Maybe M.G.L. Massachusetts General Law?, or Acts and Resolves?, or Boston City Charter?, or Ordinances?, or what other Authority?

Details.
a) When were the most recent Amendments to the Boundaries of Ward 3 ?...

b) Citation/s for Ward 3 Amendment/s ?...

c) Names of the Boundary Streets of Ward 3 ?...

d) Names of Boundary Streets of Ward 3 that are split in anyway between Wards?...

e) What were the changes to the Boundaries of Ward 3 when last Amended?...

Comment: Any category that would be better?... at http://stackexchange.com/sites

Comment: Why don't you just contact the City of Boston? Im not sure which Department exactly, but someone will direct your inquiry to the right place.

Answer (score 2):

A quick google search suggests that the [answer *might* be 1930](http://hue.uadata.org/assets/documentation/Boston_Ward_History.pdf).  I suspect that if you consult google for similar documents you may be able to refine the answer or increase the confidence in the 1930 guess.

Comment: What is that link? It's broken for me.

Comment: You're right - that link was well and truly munged. Fixed now.